# Aplicação continua a ser executada mesmo após o seu encerramento

Tags: c#, thread, clickonce

Estou tendo um problema com minha aplicação. A mesma continua na lista de processos mesmo após sua finalização, além dela, aparece também na lista a aplicação ClickOnce.

**Cenário**

Minha aplicação se comunica com uma catraca através de uma `dll`, e essa comunicação é gerenciada por uma `thread` no estado `while(true)`.

Acontece que eventualmente a `thread` é encerrada sem explicação/exception. Tenho então uma outra `thread` que verifica se a `thread` original `.isAlive`, caso seja `false` a mesma da um novo *call* na `thread`. Porém neste momento ocorre um erro, informando que não pode acessar a `dll` por que esta sendo utilizada por outra `thread`.

Segue um exemplo do código:

```
public static Thread th;
public static Thread thVerify;

void btnIniciar_Click(...)
{
    th = new Thread(() => IniciarCatraca());
    thVerify = new Thread(() => IniciarVerificacaoThread(th));
    th.Start();
    thVerify.Start();
}

public void IniciarVerificacaoThread(Thread t)
{
    try
    {
        while(true)
            if (t == null || !t.isAlive())
                th = new Thread(() => IniciarCatraca());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        CallCatch(ex);
    }
 }
```

Ele verifica corretamente se a `thread` *th* está ativa, mas ainda dá `exception` ao tentar iniciar a catraca novamente, informando que a `dll` já está em uso por outra `thread`, sendo que a `thread` foi encerrada!

Então, finalizo a aplicação e abro o gerenciador de processos. Lá estão dois processos `ClickOnce` e `ProjetoCatraca`. Caso eu abra a aplicação novamente e tente iniciar a comunicação com a catraca sem antes finalizar os processos é me retornado o mesmo erro, a `dll` está sendo utilizada por outra `thread`.

Saberiam me dizer por que a aplicação continua na lista de processos mesmo após o seu encerramento?

Isto pode ser causado pelo uso de `thread`?

Existe algum meio de verificar a existência de uma `thread` utilizando métodos diferentes dos expressos em meu código? Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Em qual parte do código a thread é encerrada?

Comment: o IniciarCatraca(); Quando a catraca demora demais para responder ou quando existe falha na comunicação com a mesma em qualquer uma das chamadas feitas pela th para a catraca, como liberar giro, verificar cartão e etc.. A comunicação com a catraca é via rede.

.

Answer (score 0):

Tem que terminar a **thread** quando for fechar o programa, senão ele fica sempre rodando, alias, para fazer de modo melhor, simpesmente crie uma **bool** estatica chamada **stopThread**, e dentro do **while** da thread, cheque se **stopThread** é ativo, se for, simplesmente de um **break**

Comment: Esta foi a alternativa que encontrei, no evento "Form_closing", defino seu valor como False, e então a thread sai do while e finaliza.